# Matrix operation on 3D grid of data using least memory/cpu

Tags: python, arrays, performance, memory

Problem Setup: I have a 3D (spatial) grid of data of size n1,n2,n3=nx,ny,nz with possibly nz=1 for a or b.  Each point in that grid has a vector (a) of data of size NDIM (=4 typically) per-gridpoint and another matrix (b) of size NDIMxNDIM per-gridpoint.  I want to compute (per-point) things like a.b or b.a most efficiently for both memory and CPU.

Essentially, I'd like to generalize [A loopless 3D matrix multiplication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344843/a-loopless-3d-matrix-operation-in-python) .  I seem to have a result that works.  But I don't understand it.  Searching google and stackoverflow leads to no help.  Please explain and further generalize!  Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
# gives a.b per point:
nx=5
ny=8
nz=3
a = np.arange(nx*ny*nz*4).reshape(4, nx,ny,nz)
b = np.arange(nx*ny*1*4*4).reshape(4, 4, nx,ny,1)
ctrue=a*0.0
for ii in np.arange(0,nx):
    for jj in np.arange(0,ny):
        for kk in np.arange(0,nz):
           ctrue[:,ii,jj,kk] = np.tensordot(a[:,ii,jj,kk],b[:,:,ii,jj,0],axes=[0,1])

c2 = (a[:,None,None,None] * b[:,:,None,None,None]).sum(axis=1).reshape(4,nx,ny,nz)
np.sum(ctrue-c2)
# gives 0 as required


# gives b.a per point:
ctrue2=a*0.0
for ii in np.arange(0,nx):
    for jj in np.arange(0,ny):
        for kk in np.arange(0,nz):
                ctrue2[:,ii,jj,kk] = np.tensordot(a[:,ii,jj,kk],b[:,:,ii,jj,0],axes=[0,0])

btrans=np.transpose(b,(1,0,2,3,4))
c22 = (a[:,None,None,None] * btrans[:,:,None,None,None]).sum(axis=1).reshape(4,nx,ny,nz)
np.sum(ctrue2-c22)
# gives 0 as required

# Note that only the single line for c2 and c22 are required -- the rest of the code is for testing/comparison to see if that line works.

# Issues/Questions:
# 1) Please explain why those things work and further generalize!
# 2) After reading about None=np.newaxis, I thought something like this would work:
    c22alt = (a[:,None,:,:,:] * btrans[:,:]).sum(axis=1).reshape(4,nx,ny,nz)
    np.sum(ctrue2-c22alt)
# but it doesn't.
# 3) I don't see how to avoid assignment of a separate btrans.  An np.transpose on b[:,:,None,None,None] doesn't work.
```

Other related links:
[Numpy: Multiplying a matrix with a 3d tensor -- Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490961/numpy-multiplying-a-matrix-with-a-3d-tensor-suggestion)
[How to use numpy with 'None' value in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962343/how-to-use-numpy-with-none-value-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your code is horrendously overcomplicated.  The products `a.b` and `b.a` can be simplified to:

```
c2 = (a * b).sum(axis=1)
c22 = (a * b.swapaxes(0, 1)).sum(axis=1)
```

Note that instead of `np.sum(ctrue - c2)` you should use `np.all(ctrue == c2)`; the former could give the wrong result if the two methods just happen to give a result with the same sum!

Why does this work?  Consider a single element:

```
a0 = a[:, 0, 0, 0]
b0 = b[:, :, 0, 0, 0]
```

Taking the tensor dot `np.tensordot(a0, b0, axes=(0, 1))` is equivalent to `(a0 * b0).sum(axis=1)`.  This is because of broadcasting; the `(4, )` shape of `a0` is broadcast to the `(4, 4)` shape of `b0` and the arrays are elementwise multiplied; then summing over the `1` axis gives the tensor dot.

For the other dot product, `np.tensordot(a0, b0, axes=(0, 0))` is equivalent to `(a0 * b0.T).sum(axis=1)` where `b0.T` is the same as `b0.transpose()` which is the same as `b0.swapaxes(0, 1)`.  By transposing `b0`, `a0` is effectively broadcasting against the other axis of `b0`; we could get the same result by `(a0[:, None] * b0).sum(axis=0)`.

The great thing about NumPy elementwise operations is that you can completely ignore higher axes as long as their shapes correspond or can broadcast, so what works for `a0` and `b0` (mostly) works for `a` and `b` as well.

Finally, we can make this much clearer using [Einstein summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation):

```
c2 = np.einsum('i...,ji...->j...', a, b)
c22 = np.einsum('i...,ij...->j...', a, b)
```